# setting class property through constructor in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, properties

I am trying to set class property through constructor in separate js file in jquery .  value passes properly , but problem is it is not saving for future use

I have tried following code

A.js

```
function ShowClassB()
{

$.getScript('../ClassB.js', function()
{

var objB = new ClassB("a");

});
}
```

---

B.js

```
var ClassA = function(options){

var x;

this.construct = function("a"){

this.x="a";

};
this.construct("a");

}

$(document).ready(function(){

var objA =new ClassA();
console.log(objA.x);

})
```

But everytime I created new object . the property values resets . I am only want to set in class property , not outside . I also tried to create simple class and by prototyping . but it is not working .

please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you've wrapped the argument name in the `construct()` definition in quotes. This is a syntax error. Remove those quotes.

```js
var ClassA = function(options) {
  var x;
  this.construct = function(value) { // change here
    this.x = value; // and here
  };
  this.construct("a");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var objA = new ClassA();
  console.log(objA.x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should note that this pattern is largely redundant though, just use an *actual* constructor:

```js
function ClassA(options) {
  this.x = options.value;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var objA = new ClassA({
    value: 'foo'
  });
  console.log(objA.x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am also trying inheritance .I try extend keyword and use super in constructor .but not able to generate exact working right syntax . can you help me in that too plz ?

Comment: Please open a new question if you have other issues.

Comment: I am learning oops in jquery . I believe you can suggest me on  next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52152397/access-method-without-object-like-static :)