# access method without object (like static)

Tags: jquery, constructor, properties

I wanted to call a class method without creating an object or calling the constructor on the document.ready event. I tried following different options but nothing worked.

```js
var objReportsInterface;

class ReportsInterface extends ReportBase {
  constructor() {
    super();
    objReportsInterface = this;
  }

  subCategories() {}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("dropdown").on('change', function()
    objReportsInterface.subCategories();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dropdown"></select>
```

I was finding a static method, but getting any example related to my code. Can I use a static method in my case?

Comment: just wanted to call class method in document.ready without created object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a static method (which is to say, a method attached to the constructor function itself rather than to an instance), use `static`:

```
class ReportsInterface {
    // ...

    static subCategories() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

then

```
$("dropdown").on('change', function()
    ReportsInterface.subCategories();
});
```

Comment: one problem i am facing that it is not letting me define variable inside class . when i do so , like var x; it is said unexpected character . any known issue ?

Comment: @NeerajVerma - I don't know what you mean by "define variable inside class." You define variables within functions/methods, not classes. There's certainly no problem doing so within `subCategories` above. Please review [MDN's page on `class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) and/or similar references to learn more about `class` syntax.